# What's wrong with this if statement

Tags: python

I'm teaching myself python with Learn Python the hard way and I've run into a problem on **ex36**.

I'm at a fairly early stage in development and I can't figure out what's wrong with my if statement. For whatever reason my code never makes it past

```
elif "1" or "2" in choice and not key.
```

even if "1" or "2" aren't in the statement. I don't understand why this is happening. Look is fine. When I was using another nested if statement for this the nested statement got past this point, but it got hung up on another point so I moved my initializing variables-Not really sure if that's a thing in python or not--I did move them though-outside of the while loop. 
Here's the code in its entirety before I ramble on too much. 
I understand that the logic isn't complete and that more than half the code isn't finished, but I need to know why this statement isn't working.

```
#write function definition statements.
def darkRoom():
    door = raw_input(">>> ")

    if "1" in door:
        lions()
    elif "2" in door:
        tiger()
    elif "3" in door:
        bear()
    else:
        print """A thunderous voice booms through the room exclaiming,
"CHOOSE DOOR 1, 2, OR 3!"""
        darkRoom()    

def lions():
#naming error somewhere here
    keys = False
    lions = False #lions are calm if false. They are pissed if true
    warning = True
    while True:

        choice = raw_input(">>> ")
        print " %r %r %r" % (keys, lions, warning)
        x = "1" or "2" not in choice and not key and lions

        if "take" and "key" in choice:
            key = True
            print """There are two doors behind the angry pride of lions.
Which door are you going to run to and open before the lions eat you?"""
            door = raw_input(">>> ")
            if "1" in door and key == True:
                threeBrickRoads()
            elif "2" in door and key == True:
                quickSand()
            else:
                youDie("You take too long to decide which door to take and the lions eat you.")
        elif "look" in choice:
            print "Looks like you're going to have to take the key from the lions"
#never gets past this statement even when 1 and two not in choice. This is what my question
#is about
        elif "1" or "2" in choice and not key:
            print "The Door is locked and the lions are starting to stare."
            lions = True
            print " %r %r %r" % (keys, lions, warning)
            print "%r" % choice
#never reaches this point. I don't know why.

        elif x and warning:
                    print """The lions leave the key and start to chase you. Quick get the
key before they catch you"""

                    warning = False
#Statement never reaches this point. It should
        elif x and not warning:
                youDie("You take too long to take the key and the lions eat you for it.")
# entering jig in statement should put me here and not at line 46
        else:
            print """"You quickly realize that doesn't do you any good.
You take another look at your surroundings"""
#don't think I need that while I have the while loop.
        #lions()

##def tiger():

##def bear():

##def threeBrickRoads():

##def quickSand():

##def sizePuzzle():

##def riddlesOnWall():

##def wolfSheepCabbage():

##def duckHunt():

##def hangman():

##def goldRoom():

##def oceanShore():

##def winScreen():

def youDie():
    print why, """You lay there pondering your mistake as
the last fleeting pulses of life slowly beat out of you."""
    #exit(0)

darkRoom()
```

Comment: The important thing to get here is that the computer is dumb. If I say `if VAR == 1 or 2`, then the computer checks to see `if VAR==1`. It then checks to see `if 2`. Because `2` is a positive integer, the `or 2` will cause the condition to always be true, regardless of `VAR`.  Your situation is similar in that the English doesn't quite conform to Python equivalent of what you're trying to say..

Comment: so `if var ===  1 or var === 2` is correct or you would need to check vars contents against a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's have a look at this line:

```
elif "1" or "2" in choice and not key:
```

What this line actually states is that it basically requires one of the following two conditions to be `True`:

1. if "1" (without anything else)
2. if "2" in choice and not key

**This is a typical mistake if you are a beginner** and you can fix this easily if you write it as follows (easiest fix):

```
elif choice in [1, 2] and not key:
```

What this means is: *If choice is equal to any of the elements contained in the list [1,2] and key is not True*.

Comment: so my x statement would be
`x = not choice in ["1", "2"] and not key and lions`
how do you format code in comments?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Put your code between these two ` symbols.

Answer (score 4):

```
elif "1" or "2" in choice and not key
```

This is interpretted as follows ("1" or (("2" in choice) and (not key)))

Since "1" is always true, this is always true. I think what you mean is:

```
elif choice in ['1', '2'] and not key
```

Comment: Which one is the first one? If you mean `if "take" and "key" in choice:`, this is also wrong. "take" is always true `"key" in choice` is sometimes true. When they are both true, then this expression is true. You should have `choice in ["take", "key"]` there as well.

Comment: So how do I structure these statements so that python interprets them the way i want python to? Is there a resource that explains how python veiws code so I can avoid this mistake in the future?

Comment: I gave you the correct syntax. Not sure I understand your question. "in" tests a single value on the left to a list on the right. You should never have more than one value on the left of an "in". Read the online docs for the "in" statement.

Comment: This is actually the first time I've seen this. Is there a website or a book that explains how python interprets things so I could know how to write things properly before I write them or should I just keep asking questions about mistakes I make that I can't fix?

Comment: The online docs help. https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#in All programming languages have order of precedence. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/operators_precedence_example.htm

Answer (score -3):

```
elif any(x in ["1", "2"] for x in choice) and not key:
```

Comment: It means if either "1" or "2" appear as a substring of choice. Your first if statement works because it is evaluated as `if True and key in choice` because non empty string evaluate to `True`

Comment: is this the correct general format for a logic statement; would I need to do something like this even if I only wanted to check to see if user input was equal to one string?

Comment: Its correct, just a lot -- its like hitting a nail with an anvil because "it will get the job done" .. but there is hammer right next to you. `choice in ['1', '2']` is more than adequate. First answer is good.